# API Proxy SSL Assistance

Tags: apigee

I received the following question.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

What I need to be able to do is configure SSL to validate the target endpoint’s SSL certificate against the base trusted roots (typically provided by the OS and/or Java). There is no documentation that tells me how to turn on SSL certificate validation or if I add a TrustStore if it will guarantee that the SSL cert is validated against that. The only tutorial I see that is related is for SSL Client Auth, which we are not using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Validation of backend SSL server certificates is explained on this [page](http://apigee.com/docs/api-services/content/client-ssl-backend-servers). Note that the page documents how to achieve mutual authentication, where the gateway would both validate the target server's SSL certificate (which you want), and send a certificate to the target as identification (which you do not want).

To validate the target's certificate, you create a truststore and upload all certificates in the trust chain for your target server. The documentation mentions only uploading the target server's certificate (which works if your target server is using a self-signed cert), but you'll want to upload the entire trust chain of certificates if you are using a non-self-signed cert. Creating and uploading to the truststore is shown in step 6 on the page above.

Then, you'll want the target endpoint configuration to look like this:

```
<TargetEndpoint name="default>
    <HTTPTargetConnection>
        <SSLInfo>
            <Enabled>true</Enabled>
            <ClientAuthEnabled>false</ClientAuthEnabled>
            <TrustStore>myTruststore</TrustStore>
            <IgnoreValidationErrors>false</IgnoreValidationErrors>
        </SSLInfo>
        <URL>https://myservice.com</URL>
    </HTTPTargetConnection>
</TargetEndpoint>
```

ClientAuthEnabled=false indicates that the gateway will not send a certificate to the target.

IgnoreValidationErrors=false will cause the connection to abort if the certificate returned by the target cannot be validated using the certificates in the truststore. IgnoreValidationErrors=false is the default, so you could leave it out and it would work as desired. However, if you are having problems communicating with your target server, it may be useful during testing to set the ignore flag to true to allow communication even if the certificate fails verification (just to isolate your problem). Just be sure to set it to false in production.

The xsd schema for the SSLInfo element can be found [here](https://github.com/apigee/api-platform-samples/blob/master/schemas/configuration/sslinfo.xsd).